# OS X: Sandboxed app can't read dragged and dropped files after waking from sleep

Tags: objective-c, macos, app-store

We have an app in the Mac App Store that is sandboxed and it reads files that users drag and drop onto it. This is all within the guidelines of how apps can access files outside of the sandbox. However, sometimes after a computer wakes from sleep OS X will no longer grant access to dragged and dropped files until the app is restarted.

This is the error it generates:

```
sandboxd: ... deny file-read-xattr /path/to/file
```

Short of restarting the app, is there any way to make Apple grant permission to files again?

Comment: You may need Security Scoped URL's friend. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043345/trouble-creating-security-scoped-bookmark

Comment: Tried the security scoped URLs and no luck. It's like the powerbox daemon stops granting the app any sort of access.