# OS X App Sandboxing and arbitrary files access - Update to Document-based?

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, document-based

My OS X app (currently not sandboxed) accesses files contained inside a directory set by the user (one chooses the path with a `NSOpenPanel` and a reference to this path is kept throughout execution). The list of files is generated via `NSDirectoryEnumerator` and I then read from and write to those files using `AVAsset` and `taglib` (in C++ with a bridging header) respectively.

As expected, enabling Sandboxing in Xcode rendered the app useless, the list of files given by `NSDirectoryEnumerator` is empty and even if it weren't, I would not be able to read from and write to the files. What are the steps I need to take to make my app sandbox-compliant?

Does my app need to be document based? Can my app really be "document-based" since I don't really have proper documents (as in: I don't have a window per file, it doesn't seem to comply to the standard document-based app model)? My app is basically just a table view with files references as rows.
Another important point: can I still use taglib to write to my files if my app is document-based ? I need to pass taglib the path to my file as a string pointer in order for it to work.

Thanks a lot, this topic is quite confusing at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to convert your app to be document-based to gain access to user selected files and security scoped bookmarks.

I can think of 2 reasons why your current code does not work in a sandboxed environment:

- You don't have the "User Selected File Access" capability set (Xcode > target > Capabilities > App Sandbox > File Access)
- You are using the path/NSString based API of the directory enumerator instead of the URL NSURL based one.

A vanilla Xcode project with Sandboxing enabled and the User selected files capabilities set, should enumerate any path obtained via `NSOpenPanel`:

```
NSOpenPanel* panel =[NSOpenPanel openPanel];
panel.canChooseDirectories = YES;
[panel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.view.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSURL *directoryURL = panel.URL;
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager
                                         enumeratorAtURL:directoryURL
                                         includingPropertiesForKeys:nil
                                         options:0
                                         errorHandler:nil];
    for (NSURL *url in enumerator) { 
        NSLog(@"url:%@", url);
    }
}];
```

If you want to store the ability to access specific folders from the sandbox across app launch/quit cycles, you will need to store a security scoped bookmark.
This post contains information persisting user selected file/directory access via app scoped bookmark:
[Trouble creating Security-Scoped Bookmark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10043345/100848)

Comment: Thanks for this, I managed to solve my problem by allowing read/write access to "user selected files" in the Xcode Sandboxing settings

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the current functionality will convert to Sandboxing just fine.

1. The user selects the directory via `NSOpenPanel` (which will invoke something called *Powerbox* in the Sandboxed environment).
2. This directory is now writable, as the user has explicitly selected it.
3. You can even maintain write access to this directory by creating a Security Scoped Bookmark and storing it away between sessions.

This has got nothing at all to do with being Document based; that is an internal design that is unrelated to Sandboxing.

Comment: Oh I see. Well actually I noticed that I can't even open a `NSOpenPanel` when I turn on sandboxing. Clicking on the button that usually opens the panel does nothing and raises an exception: `NSInternalInconsistencyException ... failed entitlements check`.

Comment: @beeb OK that sounds like you don't have something set-up property (from a project point-of-view).

Comment: Never mind, I forgot to allow read/write access to user selected files in the sandboxing parameters!

Comment: Ah yes; that will do it.  If you don't wish to persist access to a directory then there should be very little you need to change in the code itself.

Comment: I will need to persist directory access since the path is stored in the user defaults and loaded upon start if the directory exists, but that's another story! Thanks