# Mac OS - Finder Sync Extension with badges and Apple Validation

Tags: objective-c, macos, finder, appstore-sandbox

I am currently developing a Dropbox-like mac application. The application is syncing files in a folder placed in "~/" on my mac. I'd like to add badges showing sync status on the files managed by my application.

In order to do so, I have read the doc from apple : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html .

What I know so far :

- In order to show badges I need to develop a Find Sync extension
- The extension can't communicate directly with the main application (Unless it use the NSUserDefault of the application group in which I'm supposed to place both my main app and my extension)
- The app extension has to be sandboxed (so the main app has to be too in order to communicate with the extension)
- Sandboxing the app implies that I have to place my files in a directory dedicated to it (which is not compatible with my app - as the user has to be able to choose where to physically store his files).
- There are unofficial ways for showing badges (seems to be the reason why dropbox isn't available on the store)

My Question now is:

Is there a way that my app can have badges + store files anywhere on the disk (not only in sandbox allowed directories) + pass app store validation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about App Store policies and procedures, not programming

Comment: Its about the way to program it in order to pass validation. The only programming way of achieving what I need won't pass validation. I'm asking if someone knows another way ... It's a half programming / half policies subject.

Answer (score 1):

I asked Apple about this subject after having my app rejected but sadly your application has to be sanboxed in order to pass the validation.

Apps like Dropbox and Owncloud aren't validated for this reason.

You'll have to make a choice between validation, having the badges and having your files stored anywhere. You definitely can't have both.

Comment: You can store your files anywhere, even from a Sandboxed app, if you guide the user to manually choose that location. The Sandboxed app just isn't able to write there without prior user intent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495155/os-x-app-sandboxing-and-arbitrary-files-access-update-to-document-based